# python compare two lists and replace original list if there is a match

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists containing strings. I want to take each item in the `base_list` and search to see if there is a match for the first 3 characters in any values from the `custom list`. If there is a match, replace the original value in `base_list` with the one from `custom_list`. If there is no match, keep the original value.

```
base_list = ["abc123", "cde123", "efg456", "ghi123"]

custom_list = ["abc321", "efg654"]
```

Desired Output:

```
modified_base_list = ["abc321", "cde123", "efg654", "ghi123"]
```

Eventually I also want to write this new `modified_base_list` as a file containing the items, one per line.

I've tried:

```
modified_base_list = []

for custom in custom_list:
    for base in base_list:
        if custom[:3] == base[:3]:
            modified_base_list.append(custom)
        else:
            modified_base_list.append(base)


print(modified_base_list)

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for s in modified_base_list:
        f.write(s)
```

***EDITING QUESTION to account for lists that have 15k+ lines to find a faster way to do this.

Comment: What is the output? What should it be?

Comment: `["**{}**".format(x) if x[:3] in map(lambda y: y[:3],custom_list) else x for x in base_list]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension containing a generator expression:

```
base_list = ["abc123", "cde123", "efg456", "ghi123"]
custom_list = ["abc321", "efg654"] 
modified_base_list = [next((y for y in custom_list if y[:3] == x[:3]), x) for x in base_list]
# ['abc321', 'cde123', 'efg654', 'ghi123']
```

Note that I'm assuming if the same 3 character prefix occurs multiple times in `custom_list` that you only wish to take the first instance.

Comment: can you explain what the "next" statement is doing?

Comment: @JiaLi `next` finds the first occurrence for which the generator expression is `True`, if there are no occurrences, the default value is set to `x`

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that mutates the original list, replacing only those where the desired match exists:

```
>>> base_list = ["abc123", "cde123", "efg456", "ghi123"]
>>> custom_list = ["abc321", "efg654"]
>>> for i, x in enumerate(base_list):
        for test in custom_list:
            if test[:3] == x[:3]:
                base_list[i] = test
                break

>>> base_list
['abc321', 'cde123', 'efg654', 'ghi123']
```

Of course if you don’t want to modify the original list, you can create a coopy of it first using `modified_base_list = base_list[:]`.

---

You can also follow your own idea but in that case, you have to make sure that you are primarily iterating over `base_list` and won’t add items multiple times:

```
modified_base_list = []
for base in base_list:
    found = False
    for custom in custom_list:
        if custom[:3] == base[:3]:
            modified_base_list.append(custom)
            found = True
            break

    if not found:
        modified_base_list.append(base)
```

You can also use `for…else` here instead of that utility variable `found`:

```
for base in base_list:
    for custom in custom_list:
        if custom[:3] == base[:3]:
            modified_base_list.append(custom)
            break
    else:
        modified_base_list.append(base)
```

Comment: Are you sure he wanted to modify `base_list`? In his code, he create a new list.

Comment: @leaf I was following the question title that says *“replace original list”*. But if that’s not desired, you can easily create a copy first and start with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Is there any way to speed this up for a big list? My lists are created from parsing files that have 15000+ lines.

Comment: Which is the big list? You will have to iterate `base_list` completely anyway, so you cannot speed that up. If your `custom_list` is very large, you could optimize it by creating a lookup for those lines first, so you can match them in constant time without having to loop over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
res = []

for i in base_list:
    temp = list(filter(lambda j: j[:3] == i[:3], custom_list))
    if temp:
        res.append('**{}**'.format(temp.pop()))
    else:
        res.append(i)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
['**abc321**', 'cde123', '**efg654**', 'ghi123']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for this:

```
base_list = ["abc123", "cde123", "efg456", "ghi123"]

custom_list = ["abc321", "efg654"]

smaller_custom = [y[:3] for y in custom_list]

modified_base_list = ["**{}**".format(custom_list[smaller_custom.index(x[:3])]) if x[:3] in smaller_custom else x for x in base_list]
# ['**abc321**', 'cde123', '**efg654**', 'ghi123']

with open('output_data.txt','w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(modified_base_list))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi Abdou, the result list only marks the items in the original list that had matches but i need to replace the actual value also that was found in custom_list where first 3 characters match.